# Deploying to Google App Engine with eclipse Luna 4.4

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I installed eclipse Luna with the latest Google Plugin for Eclipse, App Engine SDK and GWT SDK. I tried the sample project locally, which worked fine. However I cannot deploy the project to Google App Engine, nor any other of my projects. The error is "An error occured while deploying to App Engine. See the error log for more details." However, when I look into the log section of my GAE projects no errors are listed.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on. But see if there is any more log in the Eclipse 'Error Log'. Find that by going to the menus, Window > Show View > Error Log. Just a note, the deploy command could be executed on the command line. It takes a little bit of work gathering the command parameters .

Comment: I get the error "Could not obtain an OAuth2 Access Token." The api is added to the project.

Comment: I set the project ID of my App Engine project and also added Bigquery Api to the project. I do not know what else to set or add.

Comment: I am logged in into Google App Engine Developers Console and use the Authentication type: Google Accounts Api.

Comment: I use a private key to authenticate to Bigquery and do not really get why App Engine needs OAuth2.

Comment: If you get an error, Could not obtain an OAuth2 access token, means your using the forked plugin, and I haven't fixed that yet, it's a bug.

Comment: I used the following link https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4, which is the right one?

Comment: I fixed the OAuth Token in the GPE fork yesterday. I call it the GWT Plugin for Eclipse. http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/Download.html

Answer (score 0):

So to be clear, Branflake2267's plugin is different from the official Google Plugin for Eclipse. If it's working better for you, that's great. I can confirm there are no issues with OAuth2 with the official plugin, so if you want to use that and are still having issues, please try to log in to Google again from within Eclipse itself (bottom right, 'Sign in to Google...'). The plugin won't detect if you are already signed in elsewhere.

FWIW, the reason you need an Oauth2 token is because any access to Google APIs requires OAuth2, and the plugin uses the Deployment Manager API to upload the application (as does gcloud and appcfg).